# Doctrine is not loading entities namespaces

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, namespaces, symfony-3.3

After searching and debbuging I figured out that doctrine is not loading my entities namespaces. I will show you my project config files

> AppKernel.php

```
new CEOC\PresentacionOfertaBundle\CEOCPresentacionOfertaBundle(),
new CEOC\ContactoBundle\CEOCContactoBundle(),
new CEOC\CoreBundle\CEOCCoreBundle(),
```

> config.yml

```
    # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_pgsql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
       

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

I have one entity under CEOCContactoBundle (CEOCContactoBundle:Organismo) created by doctrine:generate:entity(it worked fine!) then I did the crud with doctrine:generate:crud(it worked fine!!) but when I'm accessing I got an ORMException: Unknown Entity namespace alias 'CEOCContactoBundle' when I'm calling the EntityManager.

After that I found that the array $this->_attributes['entityNamespaces'] from Configuration.php under ORM was empty.

Why Doctrine recognize my entities namespace when I created them, when I did the crud but it does not when I using the entity manager?!!

I created my project following these steps:

> composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition
>
> composer update

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Routing configuration is irrelevant to the question, please add your Doctrine configuration (`doctrine` section from your `config.yml`)

Comment: Edited. that config is the basic I just add the config for Gedmo filters

Comment: What is the output of `bin/console doctrine:mapping:info`

Comment: @goto the output is Exception
[Exception]                                                                  
  You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current c  
  onfiguration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your m  
  apping configuration for errors.